# Our replica set config is invalid or we are not a member of it - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have started the mongodb server with replica set name 'rs01' enabled on port 27001.

Then started another command window to start the mongo db on the same port.

The status says the 'rs0' is not a member of the replica set.

```
rs0:OTHER> rs.status()
{
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1552575009, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Our replica set config is invalid or we are not a member of it",
        "code" : 93,
        "codeName" : "InvalidReplicaSetConfig",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1552575009, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
```

But, if I try to register the member, below error message happens. Any help would be appreciated.

```
rs0:OTHER> rs.initiate({_id:"rs0",members[{_id:0,host:"localhost:27001"}]})
2019-03-14T22:14:39.840+0530 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:30
rs0:OTHER> rsconf={ _id:"rs0", members: [ { _id: 0,host:"localhost:27001"}]}
{
        "_id" : "rs0",
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "host" : "localhost:27001"
                }
        ]
}
rs0:OTHER> rs.initiate(rsconf)
{
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1552575009, 1),
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "already initialized",
        "code" : 23,
        "codeName" : "AlreadyInitialized",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1552575009, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
                }
        }
}
```

mongodb

Comment: Please update your question with few more details like what is the command you used to start  the mongod, and what command you used to connect to the mongod instance.

Comment: @Nandy, What is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 5):

In my situation (a local instance with a single node in the replica set). I ran `rs.config()` and saw that the **members[0].host** was incorrect.

I copy/pasted the config to an `rs.reconfig` command, edited the host id, and had to use `{"force":true}` as second argument.

I don't know if such a "brute" method will work for different settings.

```
rs.reconfig({ 
    "_id" : "rs0", 
    "version" : 1.0, 
    "protocolVersion" : NumberLong(1), 
    "writeConcernMajorityJournalDefault" : true, 
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0.0, 
            "host" : "2f0bd979cc69:27017", 
            "arbiterOnly" : false, 
            "buildIndexes" : true, 
            "hidden" : false, 
            "priority" : 1.0, 
            "tags" : {

            }, 
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0), 
            "votes" : 1.0
        }
    ], 
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true, 
        "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : 2000.0, 
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10.0, 
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : 10000.0, 
        "catchUpTimeoutMillis" : -1.0, 
        "catchUpTakeoverDelayMillis" : 30000.0, 
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        }, 
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1.0, 
            "wtimeout" : 0.0
        }, 
        "replicaSetId" : ObjectId("6033b612985ce53324d7446c")
    }
}, {"force":true})
```

Comment: You can edit the existing config by assigning it to a variable, as you can see here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/change-hostnames-in-a-replica-set/#change-hostnames-while-maintaining-replica-set-availability but this works great. Thanks!

Comment: I've just run into this issue myself with the exact same symptoms, in particular the hostname being changed to a "random" 6-byte hex string (MAC address?). Any idea what the root cause of this is, so I can prevent re-occurence?

Comment: @Mac Sorry, I don't remember at this point.

Answer (score 0):

As per error it seems like you have not configured properly the replica set. How to setup MongoDB Replica Set , you find [here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/mongodb/setup-mongodb-replica-set/).

**For example I am writing the steps here to setup MongoDB Replica Set**

1) Start a mongod instance.

2) Start another mongod instance.

3) Start Replication.

After launcing the all mongod node instances, connect to any one node and start the mongo shell then type in command prompt

> rs.initiate()

For example

Now the mongo shell prompt would be changed to yournodeinstancename:PRIMARY>

You may also check the status using rs.status() method.

> rs.status()

for more info about rs.status() see the MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/#dbcmd.replSetGetStatus)

4) Add a MongoDB instance to the Replica Set.

> rs.add();

5) Check the Status.

You may check the status of the Replica Set by running the following command

> rs.status();

6) Getting an overview of the replica set and if current node is master

> rs.isMaster()

For further your ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/) , [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/) , [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.add/)

Answer (score 0):

It could be all of you non-arbiter members were down, so there's no chance to restore the replica set.

In this case, you may need to [force a member to be primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary/).